# Retrieve colors from PDF

Tags: command-line, pdf, colors

I have PDF files for designs and I'm wondering if there is any way I can extract the colors (as RGBA, RGB or HEX).

The best would be to annotate the PDF with the colors.

A command line tools would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52064/how-do-i-extract-the-colours-from-a-pdf

Answer (score 1):

### Install ImageMagick

- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

### Use ImageMagick's `identify`

- `identify -verbose /path/to/PDF.pdf`
- Pull out **Histogram** section

### Notes

[Similar Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52231/10805)

Comment: I don't see any Histogram: http://pastebin.com/16e6pMFF. The text is in images so that may affect it

Comment: I was using ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16.  Does the **Channel Statistics** give you what you want?

Comment: Not really, I would like specific colors, like a list, not averages